# How do I check for correlation using Decimal numbers/data with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, decimal

Thank you for your time.

I am writing some code that is checking for correlation between multiple sets of data. It works great when I am using the original data (which I am honestly unsure of which format it is in at that point), but after I run the data through some equations using the Decimal module, the data set will not show up when tested for correlation.

I feel really stupid and new lol, I am sure it's a very easy fix.

Here is a small program I wrote to demonstrate what I mean.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = [Decimal(2.3), Decimal(1.5), Decimal(5.7), Decimal(4.6), Decimal(5.5), Decimal(1.5)]
b = [Decimal(2.1), Decimal(1.2), Decimal(5.3), Decimal(4.4), Decimal(5.3), Decimal(1.7)]

h = [2.3,1.5,5.7,4.6,5.5,1.5]
j = [2.1,1.2,5.3,4.4,5.3,1.7]

corr_data1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b}) 

corr_data2 = corr_data1.corr()
print(corr_data2)

corr_data3 = pd.DataFrame({'H': h, 'J': j})

corr_data4 = corr_data3.corr()
print(corr_data4)
```

The data for both lists A & B as well as H & F are exactly the same, with the only difference of A & B being decimal formated numbers, where as H & F are not.

When the program is run, A & B returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

and H & J returns:

```
          H         J
H  1.000000  0.995657
J  0.995657  1.000000
```

How do I make it so I can utilize the data after I've ran it through my equations?

Sorry for the stupid question and thank you for your time. I hope you are all well, happy holidays!

Comment: Actually out of all the first questions asked by users that I have reviewed you have one of the best written ones, with the most example code. Props for a well comunicated question.

Comment: I don't think numpy or pandas supports the Decimal type as such.  Pandas is treating your array as an array of objects.  If you want pandas to treat them as numbers I think you'll need to convert to float.

Comment: Your list of `Decimal` objects will be turned into an `object` dtype `DataFrame` or `numpy` array.  `corr_data1.dtypes`. Some math operations work on object array, but it is hit and miss.  `corr` is one of those misses.  `corr.data1._get_numeric_data()` comes up empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas does not recognize the data as numeric values. Here is how to convert your data to float.

```
corr_data1.astype(float).corr()

#           A         B
# A  1.000000  0.995657
# B  0.995657  1.000000
```

This should also work but it actually does not.

```
pd.to_numeric(corr_data1['A'], errors='coerce')

# 0   NaN
# 1   NaN
# 2   NaN
# 3   NaN
# 4   NaN
# 5   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Pandas doesn't have any special support for the Decimal type, so it treats as "object" type.  This means that methods like `.corr` that only operate on numeric columns won't consider Decimal-valued columns to be numeric.  Many numpy and scipy functions also won't operate properly on Decimals, because Decimal objects can't be combined with ordinary floats in mathematical operations.  (It looks like `scipy.stats.pearsonr` doesn't work, but `scipy.stats.spearmanr` does.)

For most numerical operations in numpy/pandas, you'll need to convert your data to floats.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other fine answers describing how you will need floating point values for the correlation, your strategy for entering `Decimal` values is badly broken.

```py
a = [Decimal(2.3), Decimal(1.5), Decimal(5.7), Decimal(4.6), 
     Decimal(5.5), Decimal(1.5)]
```

Yields:

```py
[Decimal('2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875'), 
 Decimal('1.5'),  
 Decimal('5.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125'), 
 Decimal('4.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375'), 
 Decimal('5.5'), 
 Decimal('1.5')]
```

Which is sad, since you went to all that trouble to enter precise decimal representations, yet Python took them as `float` literals, and imposed the ugly imprecision of binary floating point upon them before they could ever reach the safe harbor of the `Decimal()` constructor. For some lucky values such as 1.5, there is no problem. `float` represents them spot-on. For others like 2.3, Evil swiftly descends.

Consider instead:

```py
a = [Decimal('2.3'), Decimal('1.5'), Decimal('5.7'), Decimal('4.6'), 
     Decimal('5.5'), Decimal('1.5')]
```

Or since that is unwieldy:

```py
a = [Decimal(x) for x in '2.3,1.5,5.7,4.6,5.5,1.5'.split(',')]
```

Either gives you the neat, precise decimals you seek:

```py
[Decimal('2.3'),
 Decimal('1.5'),
 Decimal('5.7'),
 Decimal('4.6'),
 Decimal('5.5'),
 Decimal('1.5')]
```